# phaser-ui - Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, phaser-framework

I installed phaser-ui with `npm install phaser-ui`, but when I load it into my page (with a script tag), I get an error:

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

[image: the error of console]

Comment: I personally would not trust chatgpt. my first address for information would be the projects repo/homepage https://github.com/JarLowrey/phaser-ui . depending on your usecase this might want to use a different plugin. something newer perhaps.

Comment: *btw.:** I have judt seen it, phaser-ui just works with phaser ce. checkout https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/ui-overview/ if you want ui support for phaser3.